# Find all environment variables with the same value

Tags: shell

I'm on a linux machine in the command line. I would like to find all of the environment variables with same value.

In my hypothetical/simplified example, let's imagine I run the command `printenv` and that gives me the output of:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
GOOGLE_CLOUD_SHELL=true
GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=qwiklabs-gcp-04-331618d6c19
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
CLOUD_SHELL=true
DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID=qwiklabs-gcp-04-331618d6c19
GCLOUD_PROJECT=qwiklabs-gcp-04-331618d6c19
```

I am trying to find redundant environment variables. I would like a command that shows me all of the environment variables with the value of `qwiklabs-gcp-04-331618d6c19`. So I would like a command to show me this output:

```
GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=qwiklabs-gcp-04-331618d6c19
DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID=qwiklabs-gcp-04-331618d6c19
GCLOUD_PROJECT=qwiklabs-gcp-04-331618d6c19
```

I would also be happy with this output:

```
GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT
DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID
GCLOUD_PROJECT
```

How can I do this?

Comment: An environment variable isn't redundant just because it has the same value as another one.

Comment: So do you want to `I would like to find all of the environment variables with same value.` __or__ do you want to `I would like a command that shows me all of the environment variables with the value of qwiklabs-gcp-04-331618d6c19`. That's very different.

Comment: @chepner - that's totally fair. I was interested in which ones were the same, "redundant" probably wasn't the correct choice of words. Thanks to all who answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like a command that shows me all of the environment variables with the value of qwiklabs-gcp-04-331618d6c19

Most probably I would just do:

```
env -0 | grep -zx '[^=]*=qwiklabs-gcp-04-331618d6c19' | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

If all the variables are listed in the output of `printenv` then:

```
awk -v value='qwiklabs-gcp-04-331618d6c19' '
    BEGIN {
        for (e in ENVIRON)
            if (ENVIRON[e]==value)
                print e
    }
'
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer addresses this part of the question:

> I would like to find all of the environment variables with same value

As I've been diving into [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) lately:

```bash
jq -rn '
    $ENV 
    | to_entries 
    | group_by(.value)[]
    | select(length > 1)[]
    | "\(.key)=\(.value | @sh)"
'
```

Will output, amongst any other sets of env vars that share values:

```bash
GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT='qwiklabs-gcp-04-331618d6c19'
DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID='qwiklabs-gcp-04-331618d6c19'
GCLOUD_PROJECT='qwiklabs-gcp-04-331618d6c19'
GOOGLE_CLOUD_SHELL='true'
CLOUD_SHELL='true'
```

---

For that specific value:

```bash
jq -rn --arg value qwiklabs-gcp-04-331618d6c19 '
    $ENV
    | to_entries[]
    | select(.value == $value)
    | "\(.key)=\(.value | @sh)"
'
```

Answer (score 1):

For a more general solution, consider the command

```
printenv | sort -t = -k 2 | tr = ' ' | uniq -f 1 -D  | sed 's/ /=/'
```

This will produce on stdout a list of **all** environment variables, which have the property that two variables have the same value.

The first `sort` sorts the variables by their value. The `tr` is necessary, because `uniq` does not except a field delimiter. `uniq` shows the duplicates. The `sed` just puts back the equal sign removed by `tr` for easier reading.

This works with variables containing spaces, but it breaks if the value of an environment variable contains a newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `env | cut -d= -f 2- | sort | uniq -d`; do env | grep "$i";done | cut -d= -f1
```

This will have some issues with variables containing spaces

Comment: This is interesting and filters to only the unique values, but that's not what I'm looking for in this case. In this case, I'm looking for all of the variables with the same (provided) value like: `qwiklabs-gcp-04-331618d6c19`.

Comment: I'm looking for: `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` `DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID` and `GCLOUD_PROJECT`.

I think this command would return: `SHELL` `GOOGLE_CLOUD_SHELL` `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` `JAVA_HOME` `CLOUD_SHELL`

Comment: yes, you are correct, I didn't realize you wanted to limit it (no more SO on mobile for me).   this solution I gave is not correct.